# custom mappings in revision 12

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've upgraded to Ember-Data rev 12 but can't figure out how to make my Fixture load. I tried with `key' and`sideLoadAs` on the model but to no effect.

model:

```
Sks.User = DS.Model.extend
  kudosReceived: DS.hasMany('Sks.KudoReceived', key: 'kudo_received_ids', sideLoadAs: 'kudos_received')
  name: DS.attr("string")
  email: DS.attr("string")
```

fixture:

```
Sks.User.FIXTURES = [
  id: 1
  name: 'Joe Doe'
  email: 'joe.doe@gmail.com'
  kudo_received_ids: [1, 2]
  kudos_received: [
    id: 1
    value: 2
    comment: 'Because you are nice to me!'
  ,
    id: 2
    value: 3
    comment: 'It was awesome!'
  ]
]
```

Comment: After hanging around Ember IRC channel, an awesome TeddyZ told me that  @everwakeful was right and with some minor tweaking I could make it work. It turnes out that you don’t have to define **_ids** suffixes at all, at least not in fixtures. I was so thrilled that I wrote a pro tip about it on Coder Wall: https://coderwall.com/p/ondakg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fixtures need to be an array of objects, not just an array.
Also try splitting them out into separate fixtures per type:

```
Sks.User.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Joe Doe',
    email: 'joe.doe@gmail.com',
    kudos: [1,2]
}];

Sks.Kudos.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 2,
    comment: 'Because you are nice to me!'
}, {
    id: 2,
    value: 3,
    comment: 'It was awesome!'
}];
```

And then you should need a simple relationship to hook the two together:

```
Sks.User = Ds.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    kudos: DS.hasMany('Sks.Kudos')
});

Sks.Kudos = Ds.Model.extend({
    value: DS.attr('number'),
    comment: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('Sks.User')
});
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It partly helped me in that, it is a good idea to break fixtures into seperate ones but you don't adhere to Ember conventions and I do have problem how to apply it. For example a model should be a singular form(Kudo, not Kudos). Revision 12 says that foreign keys should end with _ids. The next problem is how to use non-standard key names like I have. Anyway, thank you for taking your time!

Comment: ok, well, you can easily make my example adhere to the ember conventions. Also i notice now that in your original fixture you do not set a user_id for each kudos_received, so perhaps you mean to load them as embedded records rather than sideloaded ones?

Comment: which one should I use: embedded or sideloaded? Could you show me how I can load both of them and what are the pros and cons?